# Joomla Admin Menu disappering

Tags: joomla, admin, backend, submenu

I have a Joomla 3.1 application, and recently, when I click on any submenu of the back-end
top menu, the root menu of that submenu disappears.
Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: Is this on your own component or for every component? Have you edited any of the core Joomla files? Why don't you upgrade to Joomla 3.2 which is the latest stable release of Joomla

Answer (score 0):

Is there any plugin or extension installed by you which works on Menus?
Or you have did any customization in Joomla Core files?

Find out those and Revert them or if any plugin then un-publish that.

Comment: I unpublished all plugins/extensions I`ve created, just in case. And I can`t remember any modification of the Core files, I will check.